# How to get indexed keys on a specific range in redis?

Tags: python, redis, key-value-store

Using redis, let's say I have these keys with index on it:

```
user1:0
user1:1
user1:2
user1:3
user1:4
user2:0
user2:1
user2:2
```

How can I get the keys for let's say, user 1 from index 1-3? So, these are the results that I want:

```
user1:1
user1:2
user1:3
```

I tried these commands and got empty results:

```
LRANGE user1:* 1 4
SCAN user1:* CURSOR 1 COUNT 3
```

Another question: will it be better for me to save the index as an element in the secondary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly used `SCAN` command.

```
SCAN 0 MATCH user1:[1-3]
```

Check the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/scan) for detail.

> Another question: will it be better for me to save the index as an element in the secondary key?

Yes, you can build a secondary index for keys matching the pattern, or try [redisearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/). When your data set is large, `SCAN` is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the documentation for `LRANGE` it seems that the correct way to get your items would have been (assuming you use `RPUSH` to make the indexes):

```
redis> RPUSH user1 "one"
redis> RPUSH user1 "two"
redis> RPUSH user1 "three"
redis> RPUSH user1 "four"
redis> LRANGE user1 1 4
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
4) "four"
```

[source](https://redis.io/commands/lrange)